# Fail2ban - How to reset counter on sucess login

Tags: fail2ban

I would like reset fail2ban counters on successful login event. 
My current jail settings are :

- maxretry = 5
- bantime = 600
- findtime = 3600

Actually, if John (10.0.3.21) fails 4 times, then connects successfully, the next login attempt (all in the same hour) will ban him 10 minutes if he fails.

What i would like to have is (in the same hour, again) :

1. John fails 4 times
2. John connects successfully.
3. John can fails 5 times agein before been banned.

Thanks in advance for shed light me on about this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on the [wish list](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Talk:Features#Add_a_success_filter_to_reset_the_retry_counter):

> There is currently no way to reset the retry counter for an IP if that IP made a successful login.